# C# and MASM dll library how to debug?

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, masm

### Description

I have a bit of a problem with my project, that being said - I cannot debug the dll (written in MASM) loaded to a program written in C#. I do leave breakpoints in various places of the procedure in dll but nothing happens. Program execution just goes through the procedure without stopping.

I use Visual Studio 2010 and have the following structure of the solution:

```
Solution
|
+--+ the masm dll project
|  |
|  +- *.asm 
|  |
|  +- *.def
|
+--+ C# dll library poject 
|  
+--+ my C# project
```

Therefore I have access to the source code of the dll, and its project is within the same solution as invoking project.

However when I set the breakpoint within the C# library project it works.

And still I cannot debug this bugger. Can anyone point me towards the solution of the problem?

## Solution

Given by [Camford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249105/camford)

All you have to do in order to be able to debug unmanaged dll ( not only masm, nasm, etc. ) is to enable unamanged code debugging, that is done (in VS2010) by:

To enable debugging of unmanaged code

> 1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
> 2. Click the Debug tab.
> 3. Select the Enable unmanaged code debugging check box.

(from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tdw0c6sf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

Comment: I am unaware of Visual Studio being able to break directly into a MASM source file. When it does break, it will break directly into the disassembly and it will be pure ASM, without the fancy MASM macros.

Comment: To be honest that would really do for me but it does not happen either! Execution just falls through the breakpoints like they weren't set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable unmanaged code debugging in your c# project's Debug setting. If that still doesn't work, since you have the asm code, you can insert `int 3` in your asm as a hardcoded break instruction, and rebuild your dll.